# a man riding a horse

Tags: punctuation, commas

1. He was a man tall and strong, riding a horse like a knight, humming a tune.
2. He was a man tall and strong, riding a horse, like a knight, humming a tune.

Is he like a knight or is he riding a horse like a knight?

I think in both cases he is riding a horse like a knight.

Many thanks

Comment: Is the horse like a knight?

Answer (score 2):

### The commas distribute 'he was'

The subject / verb of the sentence is 'he was'.  This subject and verb are distributed to each of the clauses separated by commas, so the extra comma in (2) does change the meaning.

(1)
He was a man tall and strong.
He was riding a horse like a knight.  [He was riding in the manner that a knight rides a horse]
He was humming a tune.

(2)
He was a man tall and strong.
He was riding a horse.
He was like a knight.
He was humming a tune.

Comment: What is the difference between `riding a horse like a knight` and `riding a horse, like a knight`?

Comment: @Rakib In the first case the way he was riding the horse was like a knight rides a horse.  In the second, he was riding a horse, in an unspecified manner.  He was also like a knight, but we are not told HOW he was like a night.  The comma divides the two thoughts, the lack of a comma makes them part of the same thought.

Answer (score 1):

In speech, the parsing rhythms, as subtle as they may be, isolate the constituents, and guide the auditor's parsing. Here's a crude markup, crude because the micro-pauses (...) are of varying duration and the ... doesn't reflect the nuances:

He was a man ... tall and strong ... riding a horse ... like a knight ... humming a tune.

If the horse were like a  knight (ignoring common sense) then the pauses (...) would be as below, with no micro-pause between "horse" and "like a knight":

He was a man ... tall and strong ... riding .. a horse like a knight ... humming a tune.

In texts, one of the roles of punctuation is to identify constituent boundaries, especially when there's some ambiguity that could result in misunderstanding (which there isn't in the example provided).